# async module (async.waterfall)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am using async.waterfall module.
scenario : 
in first callback function I am populating the data from the DB and passing the output of that in second callback function where I am send a mail notification and then updating the DB with a mail flag.

Code :

```
async.waterfall(
function(callback){
   // data population code
},
function(datafromDB, callback){
    NotificationManager.sendEmailToUser('MAIL', variableDetails, email, callback); 
   // code to update the database
}],
  function(err,result){
   //callback
}
```

I want the user details in result which I should be getting in callback function once the code to update the database is called but before that while sending the mail callback function is getting resolved. Is there any way to get the user details in the result?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more clear? You want the user details in your last callback after sending the mail but before updating the database. Right? or is it something else?

Comment: No once the mail is sent the callback is getting resolved there and not getting the result of the second callback to the results, instead it is giving undefined which is the output coming from the mail notification callback

Answer (score 0):

you can make the second callback return two parameters ex: datafromDB, notification

```
async.waterfall(
function(callback){
   // data population code
},
function(datafromDB, callback){
    NotificationManager.sendEmailToUser('MAIL', variableDetails, email, callback); 
    // code to update the database
    callback(null, datafromDB, notification);
}],
  function(err,result){
   //callback
}
```